# NetworkManager: "Wireless security" only shows "None", no way to connect to WPA2

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, wpa2

Here is how the "Connect to Hidden Wireless Network" dialog used to look with Ubuntu 2011.04:

[image]

The "Wireless Security" list showed different protocols, including the one I want (WPA & WPA2 Personal)

PROBLEM: With Ubuntu 2012.04 (on another laptop), only "None" is shown in "Wireless security":

[image]

QUESTION: Why are the other options no longer available in 2012.04?
*I have just installed it, it is in an out-of-the-box state.*

Comment: Solved by reinstalling 12.04, this time it works...