# Password required but dialog won't let me type it

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, wpa2

On Ubuntu 2012.04 I open "Connect to Hidden Wireless Network", type the network name, click connect. After a minute the dialog below appears:

[image]

I can only cancel... not very helpful.
Why does the dialog not just offer me to type the password?

On Ubuntu 2011.04 I am asked for a password and it just works...

The network is WPA2 Personal, but [this other issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143523/networkmanager-wireless-security-only-shows-none-no-way-to-connect-to-wpa2) means I have to select "None" for security.

Comment: This may help you: http://askubuntu.com/a/28199/37006

Comment: Are there any unrecognized special characters (e.g. `_´äöü8`) in your key?

Comment: @BasharatSial: I have no keyring problem.

Comment: @Takkat: the SSID contains only letters and underscores. The password only contains numbers.

Comment: Are you using TKIP or AES with WPA2?

Comment: @izx: TKIP but usually on Ubuntu I don't need to specify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by reinstalling 12.04, this time it works...